# How can I add a file in the Google Cloud SSH? I am in need to host a website and wants to add .HTML file in SSH command line

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh

I am going to host a website and needed to add a file (simple HTML file) in SSH command line in the location /var/www/html.

Comment: Do you want to just create or edit a file on your server while connected via SSH ? Please provide more details what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Yes I have to add a file to SSH terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the file location path I'm assuming you're running Linux (most probably Debian since it's the default solution for many GCP's VM's).

When you connect via SSH to your VM (it doesn't matter what kind of software terminal it is) or [GCP's console](https://console.cloud.google.com) and SSH button (which opens up a new window) there is a way to create and edit files that way.

For small files (like HTML page) you can use `[nano]`[2](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/42980/the-beginners-guide-to-nano-the-linux-command-line-text-editor/).

When you log in to your instance create a file with nano (if it's not there):

`sudo nano /var/www/html/index.html` - it will open up the nano and you will see empty file. If `index.html` already existed you will see it's contents.

I assume you already have the file ready on your local computer so now just open it with text editor and copy it's contents to the nano's window (ctrl+c & ctrl + v work).

Next save the file with nano <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> and close it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>.

Now reload the webserver service (lets assume you use nginx) with `sudo service nginx reload`.

Comment: Were you able to try my solution ?